# Reading generated image from OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl

I have the following OpenCl kernel code:

```
kernel void generateImage(global write_only image2d_t output_image)
{
    const int2 pos = {get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)};
    write_imagef(output_image, (int2)(pos.x, pos.y), (float4)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

How can I read the generated image on the CPU side to render it ? I am using plain C. Also a link to some nice tutorial would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The [`clEnqueueReadImage()` function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadImage.html) is an image object's equivalent to a buffer object's `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` function - with similar semantics. The main difference is that (2D) images have a "pitch" - this is the number of bytes by which you advance in memory if you move 1 pixel along the y axis. (This is not necessarily equal to *width* times *bytes per pixel* but can be larger if your destination has special storage/alignment requirements.)

The alternative, much as is the case with buffer objects, is to memory-map the image using [`clEnqueueMapImage()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapImage.html).

How you further process the image once your host program can access it depends on what you're trying to do and what platform you're developing for.